# How do I find the original MAC addresses on linux interface-bounding process in Java?

Tags: java, mac-address, network-interface

[interface-bounding](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bonding):The Linux bonding driver provides a method for aggregating
multiple network interfaces into a single logical bonded interface. The logical bounded interface will have only one MAC address,which is bounded from one of the original interfaces. `ifconfig` will show all the original interfaces with the same MAC address.

Now,I'm going to found the original MAC address of each interface in Java.How ?

I has confirmed that I can't find them through `NetworkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()` and `NetworkInterface.getSubInterfaces()`

Any other ways?

**UPDATE:**

before bounding:
[image]

after bound eth1 and eth2 to bound0:
[image]

The java code show interfaces info:

```
ALL interfaces:[name:bond0 (bond0), name:eth0 (eth0), name:lo (lo)]
they are [{netIf bond0,host 192.168.122.38,mac 525400F801B9,ip 192.168.122.38}, {netIf eth0,host hatest02,mac 5254008C5B48,ip 192.168.10.38}]
```

Comment: Did you try `NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress()` as mentioned in the blos post: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/ ?

Comment: Yes,I did that for each NetworkInterface returned by NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(),And I could not found the other one.

Comment: You could also call ifconfig from java and parse the output

Comment: ifconfig's will show the original interfaces,but they are all bounded to the same MAC address as the interface 'bound0'

Comment: I think you'll have to walk the data from /proc/net/bonding to determine this information if it's not available as one of the interfaces in java

Comment: Yes,the file /proc/net/bonding/bond0 show the slave Interface's MAC address.

Comment: Please add your solution as answer and mark it at solved

Answer (score 8):

```
cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
```

Will show you the original mac's for both bonded interfaces

Full output, less private data below:

```
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)
Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: None
Currently Active Slave: eno49
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eno49
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 28:80:23:xx:xx:ec
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eno50
MII Status: down
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 28:80:23:xx:xx:ed
Slave queue ID: 0*
```

Answer (score 0):

cat /proc/net/bonding/bond**X**

where bond**X** is the name of your bonded interface

Answer (score -1):

NetworkInterface is useless, IMHO.  I've never gotten reliable information from it.  Execute `ifconfig` and parse the output, that is your best option.

UPDATE: awesome, somebody downvoted.  So post an answer and show what works, because I stand by the assertion that NetworkInterface is unreliable.  A modern alternative to `ifconfig` that is capable of showing bonding information is `ip link show type bond`.

Comment: ifconfig will hiding the unactive slave interfaces' MAC address,as mentioned in the UPDATE part of question body.And,ifconfig in fedora & sles has different output format.